# ibm vs oracle java casting difference

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i have a piece of code

```
 for(Importer user : getUserRecords(query.getResultList())){...
```

where the called function is

```
protected List<Importer> getUserRecords(List<Object[]> users){
    List<Importer> result = new ArrayList<Importer>();
    for (Object[] obj : users) {
        UserRecord userRecord = (UserRecord) obj[0];
        ...
        result.add(userRecord);
    } return result;
```

everything is ok in eclipse and in maven when i use ibm java 1.6.
When i switch to oracle java 1.8 in eclipse it is also ok but maven compiler complains that the getUserRecords returns wrong types

> incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to com.volvo.cmslms.database.entities.importer.Importer

however when i change the code to

```
List<Importer> userImporters = getUserRecords(query.getResultList());
        for(Importer user : userImporters){...
```

everything is ok everywhere. I dont have a clue what the issue is here.

Comment: forgot to write that UserRecord extends Importer

Comment: Are you using the correct JDK to compile on command line with Maven?

Comment: Which version do you use exactly? JDK 8u152? If not, can you reproduce this issue with [JDK 8u152](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)?

Comment: in eclipse and maven i use the 152

Comment: @mscislawin any common with this question ?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37858061/incompatible-types-java-lang-object-cannot-be-converted-to-t